# Can Electric Field and Gravitational Field be added vectorially?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, dimensional-analysis

As both fields follow Superposition Principle, can they be added to get a total field at any region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields are different. They interact with different substances, so it would not make much sense to mathematically add them.

But gravitational **forces** and electric **forces** can be added. For example in Newton's 2nd law. Forces are forces, regardless of their origins. But their origins, in this case the fields, might be fundamentally different.

Comment: agree with steeven. the key point here is that there's no way to mathematically transform a gravitational field into an electric field. this means, for example, that there is no configuration of electric charges or current flows which yield a gravitational field, and no configuration of uncharged masses which could produce an electric field. Although it would be fun if there was!